# FreeBSD hard drive performance

Tags: freebsd, hard-disk, performance

With FreeBSD 11, the system behaves sluggishly while copying large amounts of files from the system partition to another hard drive. Any time an operation is performed (like opening a terminal) for which access to the system partition is necessary, lags up to a few seconds happen. Is there any way to avoid this, to deprioritize the HD access of the `cp` command? Renicing does not help.

Comment: 100 MB/s is 800Mbps...

Comment: AFAIK 100MB/s sequential read/write is quite decent for spinning drives. Wouldn't be too surprised either if it slows down system response if one of the drives is also the system drive.

Comment: You don't need `nice`, but [`ionice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice)

Comment: @Philippos `ionice` does exist under FreeBSD???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do when "nice" isn't good enough (FreeBSD)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204987/what-to-do-when-nice-isnt-good-enough-freebsd)

Comment: Sorry, I did not know this. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204987/what-to-do-when-nice-isnt-good-enough-freebsd) is about performance breakdown on other tasks, but maybe the first answer can help you though.

Answer (score 0):

[Try looking at `idprio`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rtprio&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports) and set `cp` to an idle time priority to run when no other tasks are waiting to be run. Read the `idprio` manual for potential caveats.

There may also be some tweakable filesystem options depending on what filesystem you are running.